# Overflow: hidden not working in Google Chrome with iFrames

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css, iframe

Below is the code which is working fine in IE but it is not working in Chrome/safari as I am getting horizontal scroll bar.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server" Style="width: 640px; height: 530px">
<iframe id="frm1" frameborder="0" width="100%" scrolling="no" height="100%" src="../pop.htm" style="overflow: hidden;"></iframe></asp:Panel>
```

What else I need to do to make it work perfectly in all the browsers.
Thanks

Comment: is there any answer for it?

Comment: properties you have given are almost correct. try to change that `height:"100%" width="100%"` to manual like : `height:"530px" width="640px"` or provide some more code.

Comment: @Era : no, that should be fine as `100%` will cover the area available...

Comment: @user1301587 : placing `style="overflow: hidden;"` in `panel` instead of `iframe` isn't an option???

Comment: Yes it should be 100%. I also tried to set it in panel but it is also not working!!!!

Comment: @user1301587 : can you provide a basic fiddle or atleast show your css for reference...that would be helpful!! :)

Comment: this is all the code which i am using for Iframe.

Comment: Oh my goodness the same peace of code is now working fine....:P I guess my old code was cached!!!!

Comment: This is why I was surprised that despite everything is right in the code and why it was not working...I cleared cache/cookies and now it is working absolutely fine.